# Cgroup - no space left on device

Tags: debian, cgroup

I have Debian 7 box and little issue:

```
mkdir /cgroups/test
echo 500 > /cgroups/test/cpu.shares
echo 3167 > /cgroups/test/tasks
bash: echo: write error: No space left on device
```

How can I fix it?

---

In fstab:

```
cgroup /cgroups cgroup defaults 0 0
```

I have installed: cgroup-bin, libcgroup1, libpam-cgroup

Comment: Provide the mount options for your cgroups mount.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a disk issue. Think this is more cgroup related. I might have some time to look into this tonight ...

Comment: cgroups is virtual - no need extra hdd space, but i have free space

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have been able to reproduce and solve the issue doing :

```
/bin/echo 0 >/cgroups/test/cpuset.mems
/bin/echo 0 >/cgroups/test/cpuset.cpus
```

Seems that CPUs and Memory Nodes' list for the cpuset were created with empty values when the `test` folder was created.

Hope it will work for you also.

Comment: Thanks U! It works! :) I can't add +1 vote to your post because I don't have required reputation.

Comment: Hello!  Has a bug report been filed for this?  I didn't see one with a cursory search.  This one needs to go upstream.  https://bugzilla.kernel.org  Thanks.  At the very least, we should get a warning in the kernel logs.